# Automating Import of large csv files(~3gb) with C#

Tags: sql, csv, sqlbulkcopy, csvhelper

I am a bit new to this but my goal is to import the data from a csv file into a sql table and include additional values for each row being the file name and date. I was able to accomplish this using entity frame work and iterating through each row of the file but with the size of the files it will take too long too actually complete.

I am looking for a method to accomplish this import faster. I was looking into potentially using csvhelper with sqlbulkcopy to accomplish this but was not sure if there was a way to pass in the additional values needed for each row.

```
public void Process(string filePath)
    {
        InputFilePath = filePath;
        DateTime fileDate = DateTime.Today;
        string[] fPath = Directory.GetFiles(InputFilePath);
        foreach (var file in fPath)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);


            char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };

            try
            {
                using (var db = new DatabaseName())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    string line;
                    int count = 0;
                    int sCount = 0;

                    reader.ReadLine();
                    reader.ReadLine();

                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        count++;
                        string[] row = line.Split(delimiter);
                        var rowload = new ImportDestinationTable()
                        {
                            ImportCol0 = row[0],
                            ImportCol1 = row[1],
                            ImportCol2 = TryParseNullable(row[2]), 
                            ImportCol3 = row[3],
                            ImportCol4 = row[4],
                            ImportCol5 = row[5],
                            
                            IMPORT_FILE_NM = fileName,
                            IMPORT_DT = fileDate
                        };
                        db.ImportDestinationTable.Add(rowload);
                        if (count > 100)
                        {

                            db.SaveChanges();
                            count = 0;
                        }

                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //ReadLine();
                }

        }
    }


    static int? TryParseNullable(string val)
    {
        int outValue;
        return int.TryParse(val, out outValue) ? (int?)outValue : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do the file processing outside the database and generate a ready-to-load sequential file. Use the database utilities to import this file without coding to the database.

Comment: What happens to performance if you modify `count > 100` to, say `count > 1000` or `count > 10000`?  Have you profiled to determine where you are taking time?

Comment: `CsvHelper` is not going to parse the file faster than `reader.ReadLine()`.  What it will do is correctly handle **escaping**.  As it is `line.Split(delimiter);` will not work correctly if your text fields contain embedded delimiters.  `CsvHelper` (or [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-5.0) or any other proper CSV parser) will handle that for you automatically.